# Make python mixins usage safer (and telling linter to shut up)

Tags: python, class

Consider this toy mixin:

```py
class MyMixin:
    def foo(self):
        return self.x + self.y
```

It is to be used along with classes that actually provide an `x` and a `y`. But:

- The linter doesn't know that, so complains
- I can make a class, and an instance thereof, and only get a complaint, in the form of a run time `AttributeError`, when I try to use `foo` (see next code)

```py
class A(MyMixin):
    def __init__(self, x=0):
        self.x = x
        
a = A(10)  # no problem!
a.foo()  # problem: AttributeError: 'A' object has no attribute 'y'
```

Instead, I'd like

- the linter not to complain about missing `x` and `y` in `MyMixin`
- to be notified when I'm using it without providing the necessary attributes (this notification could come in the form (all optional) of linter, syntax error when making `A`, and/or when instantiating `A`)

I feel meta-classes can some of this, but can already hear the tales of woes when mentioning the meta-monster.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Focusing first on your main problem: how to know if an attribute is missing when creating a class that uses the mixins. Indeed - there is no plain way for Python code, even with its introspection capabilities to know about which attributes are set or needed inside a method.

Linters to this by "cheating": they parse the code and look at it statically, from "outside" the Python code, not from "inside" it. I.e.: they follow the text of the source code, while, by using introspection at runtime, we have the function as an object, and we'd have to track its bytecode to see which attributes it would be using.

However, if you can live with declaring your needed attributes in the class body itself, I think it is possible to both silence the linter, and have Python scream if you incorporate methods that need an attribute a class is not aware of.

We would have use the features provided by abstract base classes, and just stretch them a bit, so that needed attributes have to be overriden in a class using your mixin.

So here it is, with some boilerplate to chill out other warnings in the linter:

```py
"""module doc"""


from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

# This thing works as an "abstract attribute": 
# The class can't be instantiated unless it is overriden
# in the class declaration:
AbstractField = lambda: property(abstractmethod(lambda s: s))

class Aa(ABC):
    """doc"""

    x = AbstractField()
    y = AbstractField()

    def b_b(self):
        """doc"""
        return self.x + self.y


class Bb(Aa):
    """doc"""
    x = 0
    y = 0

    def __init__(self):
        """doc"""
        print(self.b_b())

# Class 'Bb' can be declared, but if both x and y are not
# declared in the class body, instantiating it would raise
# a runtime error, due to the abstractclass mechanism:

b = Bb()
```

```py
(env39) [gwidion@village tmp01]$ pylint -d R0903 module.py 

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

Now, since you are paying attention to linters and similar tools that at times get more in the way than they help, you probably will want to create
proper annotations for those attributes as well.

I am not that versed in proper type-hinting, but creating a Union of "property" and the actual type the fields should contain at runtime seems to do the job (i.e.: MyPy runs with no errors or warnings, linter does not show errors, and code works as expected):

```
"""module doc"""


from abc import ABC, abstractmethod as abstract
from typing import Union

ABIntField = Union[property, int]


AbstractField = lambda: property(abstract(lambda s: s))

class Aa(ABC):
    """doc"""

    x: ABIntField = AbstractField()
    y: ABIntField = AbstractField()

    def b_b(self):
        """doc"""
        return self.x + self.y


class Bb(Aa):
    """doc"""
    x = 0
    y = 0

    def __init__(self):
        """doc"""
        print(self.b_b())


b = Bb()
```

I tried to think of other ways to go there - and although it would be possible, if hard, to have a metaclass (or some `__init_subclass__` code) that would find out about the needed attributes for the mixin methods, without having to declare them in the body, the converse: having the linter know that "those attributes are covered" would not be possible that way.

The way described above is the "obvious thing to do". Depending on the project it could be worth to pack more functionality on `AbstractField` getting to the point the `ABIntField` annotation is not needed.

Comment: Thanks @jsbueno -- nice exhaustive answer. I've accepted and upvoted. I'll also post an answer containing decorator to perform your first solution automatically, in case you care to comment.

Answer (score 1):

I took @jsbueno's answer and packed it into a decorator that can be used to perform his set up on any class.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod as abstract

AbstractField = lambda: property(abstract(lambda s: s))

def mixin_requiring(*attributes):
    """Decorator (factory) to make wrapped class a mixin requiring some specific attributes to exist"""
    def mk_mixin_class(cls):
        wrapped_cls = type(cls.__name__, (cls, ABC), {})
        for a in attributes:
            for attr_name in a.split():
                setattr(wrapped_cls, attr_name, AbstractField())
        return wrapped_cls
    return mk_mixin_class
```

The definition of his `Aa` class then becomes:

```py
@mixin_requiring('x y')  # or mixin_requiring('x', 'y')
class Aa:
    """doc"""

    def b_b(self):
        """doc"""
        return self.x + self.y
```

Comment: Linters also suck at `setattr()` with dynamic names so it might still yell at you for nonsense.